# Does Visual C++ Push Eight Bytes for DWORDs? (If so, why?)

Tags: c++, stack, 64-bit

Without knowing it, at first, I wrote some code that involved a `long long` variable. Mistakenly treating it as a `long`, I passed it to `printf`, which actually printed the value it contained (as the high bits were all zeroes).

Eventually, I found out I was using a `long long`, and that got me interested in why `printf` seems so resilient against the kind of error I had made. Eventually I wrote this:

```cpp
int main()
{
    long a = 1;
    long long b = 2;
    long c = 3;
    long d = 4;
    long long e = 5;
    long f = 6;
    long g = 7;
    long long h = 8;
    long i = 9;
    long long j = 10;

    printf("%d %I64d %d %d %I64d %d %d %I64d %d %I64d\n", a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j);
    printf("%I64d %I64d %I64d %I64d %I64d %I64d %I64d %I64d %I64d %I64d\n", a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j);
    printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d\n", a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

The first of those `printf`s associates the right format specifier for the type of each subsequent argument after the format string. The second applies the specifier for a `long long`, and the third specifies a plain old `long` (well, an `int`, to be precise, right?).

Here's the output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1 2 3 -3689348818177884156 5 -3689348818177884154 -3689348818177884153 8 -3689348818177884151 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Now this kind of puzzled me, because I expected the compiled code for that call to `printf` pushed four bytes onto the stack for the arguments that were `long`s, and eight bytes for those that were `long long`s. However, if that were the case, the `printf` code would have been looking in the wrong places after processing the first incorrect format specifier. Yet, as my output shows, `printf` never got lost, associating the matching specifier with its argument in each case. Only the second line fails to print the right values, but that's for a reason that turns out to make perfect sense, but also leads to my question.

To find out what was going on, I had the compiler (VS2015's VC++, x64) produce an assembly listing. Here's the first call to `printf`:

```
; 20   :    printf("%d %I64d %d %d %I64d %d %d %I64d %d %I64d\n", a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j);

    mov rax, QWORD PTR j$[rbp]
    mov QWORD PTR [rsp+80], rax
    mov eax, DWORD PTR i$[rbp]
    mov DWORD PTR [rsp+72], eax
    mov rax, QWORD PTR h$[rbp]
    mov QWORD PTR [rsp+64], rax
    mov eax, DWORD PTR g$[rbp]
    mov DWORD PTR [rsp+56], eax
    mov eax, DWORD PTR f$[rbp]
    mov DWORD PTR [rsp+48], eax
    mov rax, QWORD PTR e$[rbp]
    mov QWORD PTR [rsp+40], rax
    mov eax, DWORD PTR d$[rbp]
    mov DWORD PTR [rsp+32], eax
    mov r9d, DWORD PTR c$[rbp]
    mov r8, QWORD PTR b$[rbp]
    mov edx, DWORD PTR a$[rbp]
    lea rcx, OFFSET FLAT:??_C@_0CL@GHCEKCAD@?$CFd?5?$CFI64d?5?$CFd?5?$CFd?5?$CFI64d?5?$CFd?5?$CFd?5?$CFI64d@
    call    printf
```

Now, it has certainly been a long time since I did any assembly programming, but, if I read that correctly, it appears that each argument from right to left is being put into memory locations relative to the `rsp` register that are, every one of them, eight bytes apart from each other, regardless of whether or not the value requires eight bytes for its representation. (I note that this statement actually  does not apply to values `a`, `b`, and `c`, which are kept in registers, not memory; an optimization for short argument lists, perhaps?)

Thus, it all makes sense: `printf` never gets lost, because it knows (or the coder who wrote it knew) that each argument will be found eight bytes away from its neighbor, *regardless* of that argument's size. (The few values that were printed incorrectly can, I think, be explained by the fact that the compiled code stored four-byte `DWORD`s for those values, and there may have been non-zero bytes in the high four bytes of the `QWORD` that `printf` expected to find in those locations.)

So, it seems to me that the compiler effectively maintains a stack (is "stack" the right word here?) with eight-byte entries in it, regardless of whether or not eight are always needed.

Why?

**UPDATE:**

The question I've asked (and that Hans Passant has answered) doesn't rely on `printf` or even variadic argument lists. It's inherent in how the fifth and higher arguments to functions are handled for the x64 architecture.

For example, calling this function:

```cpp
void sub(long a, long b, long c, long d, long e, long f)
{

}
```

gets you this assembler code:

```
; 28   :    sub(a, c, d, f, g, i);

    mov eax, DWORD PTR i$[rbp]
    mov DWORD PTR [rsp+40], eax
    mov eax, DWORD PTR g$[rbp]
    mov DWORD PTR [rsp+32], eax
    mov r9d, DWORD PTR f$[rbp]
    mov r8d, DWORD PTR d$[rbp]
    mov edx, DWORD PTR c$[rbp]
    mov ecx, DWORD PTR a$[rbp]
    call    ?sub@@YAXJJJJJJ@Z           ; sub
```

where, again, we see that arguments that are `long`s are passed to the function in memory locations that are eight bytes apart.

Comment: My guess is that this has to do with being on a 64-bit processor, which may like things aligned on eight-byte boundaries. But I hate guessing and hope someone can point me to reliable info. Thanks!

Comment: Undefined behavior is just that - _undefined_. Throw in a few `%s`'s around your `%d`'s and see what happens.

Comment: Do note that if the specifier and type do not match then you have undefined behavior.  The results you get may be different on different implementations.

Comment: ... and, although it is sometimes _possible_ to analyse the symptoms of UB on a particular system in a particular run, it is almost never useful to do so. (That's why you're about to get a brazillian "stahp; it's UB" comments and answers.)

Comment: It is demanded by the x64 abi, parameters that need to be passed through  the stack (5th and up) are aligned to 8.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235286.aspx

Comment: Bullseye, @HansPassant! Man, you're good.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, Yeah, seems you're right. But my question would still come up if it were any generic function that took `long`s as arguments, wouldn't it? This isn't about `printf`, really. It's about why the compiler does what it does.

Comment: The compiler does what it does because that's what you told it to do. This issue is in part about `printf` since it uses a variadic argument lists that allow you to easily tell the runtime to do the wrong thing.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious, see my update. You're right, the funky behavior of `printf` is because I am lying to it. But the question of why arguments are being aligned on octobyte boundaries doesn't depend on the presence of variadic argument lists. It's just The Way Things Are :) .

Comment: Yep and @Hans should write that as an _answer_!

Comment: @HansPassant that's something I didn't know yet. Definitely worthy of a complete answer, along with all the "don't rely on undefined behavior" warnings.

Comment: It is an excessively boring subject that isn't going to make anybody program differently.  Raymond Chen made a vague promise he'll blog about it some day, I trust he'll know how to make it more interesting.

Comment: @HansPassant, speak for yourself :) ! No, it's not particularly practical info, but I personally love knowing this kind of machine-level stuff. Please do write it up as an answer and I'll check the green marker. Might mention that the UB aspect is more confusing than relevant. It's what caused me to investigate, but it's not what the question asked, nor is it essential to either the question nor the answer. Another good job, SO posse, thanks!